# How to View entries in a SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: database

As you can tell I am quite new at this, but is it possible to view entries in a database?

I have tried looking in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, but I was lost!

Sorry to sound a bit dumb

J.J.I Mahone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. In SQL Server 2012 Management Studio you can **right click** on a table and select '**select rows**'. By this you can see the entries of each table of the database.

[Here is the image](http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.wp.com%2Fwww.dirkstrauss.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F11%2FSQL-Server-2012-Select-or-Edit-All-Rows.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dirkstrauss.com%2Fhow-to%2Fselect-and-edit-all-rows-in-sql-server-2012&h=327&w=356&tbnid=Qy7_o4BQD9AyDM%3A&zoom=1&docid=Wg_oZKJn7G39YM&ei=CNdxVKK6DNivabnKgsgO&tbm=isch&ved=0CB0QMygEMAQ&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=780&page=1&start=0&ndsp=15).